# How to hide header component in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am having a React app like this one [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvokl2yjnl) I want to hide the global header component from page like Login and Signup. I can't find any approach for this in React-Router-v4 over internet. Could anybody please shed some light on me to proceed further?

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div className="app-wrapper">
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </main>
      <footer>
        &copy; Acme Inc. 2017
      </footer>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to hide/show the header based on the authorization status, then you can pass an object containing the authorization status to the Header component based on which it will render the menu items.

I've forked the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjyl9y17rx

Here I'm just passing a boolean value for authorization status, but you get the idea.

The other option to render a route based on the path is to use a regex in the path, which I believe is supported, going by this conversation:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/391

Comment: Thank you! the first option is more than enough for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `withRouter` Higher Order component to access `props.location` object in your App component and check if user is on login or signup page using `props.location.pathname`

keep in mind that you don't have to use `withRouter` component if your component in which you want to access `props.match` or `props.location` object is rendered by `<Route/>`

```
import {Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const App  = (props) => {
return(
  <Router>
    <div className="app-wrapper">
     {
      props.location.pathname!=='/login' ? <Header/>:null
     }
      <main>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </main>
      <footer>
        &copy; Acme Inc. 2017
      </footer>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
};


export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: Is there any more elegant way to do this without checking a pathname? How the code will look if I have 100 different components, if 50 of them need Header and 50 don't?

Comment: Thank you. By using your solution, I used `this.props` insted of `props`. it helped me.

Comment: I get the error , withRouter cannot use otuside the router , Is there a solution to this ?

Comment: @Thanveer Shah you need to import Router from react-router-dom in your App.js and wrap your jsx with Router component or wrap it around <App/> in your index.js

Answer (score 0):

I did this by importing useLocation hook in header component

```
const location = useLocation()
```

```
{
  location.pathname=='/signin' ? <Link to='/' >Back to Homepage</Link> : 
     <div class="header">
      <li>...<li>
       .
       .
       .  
     <div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can hide it without using location

```
<Router>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login">
                  <LogIn />
                </Route>
                <Fragment>
                  <SideBar />
     <main>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          </main>
          <footer>
            &copy; Acme Inc. 2017
          </footer>
                </Fragment>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
```

Comment: i had same issue in my  project i solved  it  by wrapping it with fragment